# sendkeys of selenium in python dose not work

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, sendkeys

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#open Firefox
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
#open arbitrary ur
url="https://www.scopus.com/search/form.uri?display=basic"
driver.get(url)
#click on input  element for writing special word
search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBoxSearch"]/label""")
search.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
#write your special word
search.send_keys("internet of things")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
search.submit()
```

Error stack trace :

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <label class="inputTextLabel activeInputLabel"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

The url is opened and x-path is identified, but send_keys doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: No element with `id="txtBoxSearch"` in the webpage..

Comment: You must have subscribe for going to the url.

Comment: That does not help to answer you

Comment: I think you have too many quotes there: `find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBoxSearch"]/label""")`. I recomend you to chage for this one: `find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtBoxSearch']/label")`

Comment: It is correct 100%.

Comment: You're trying to send keys to `label` node while you should handle `input` node... try `search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBoxSearch"]/input[@type="text"]""")` instead

Comment: That is great. my problem is solved. Thank your trying. Please add your comment as an answer to vote it.

Comment: @hamed_baziyad, note that there is no need to use `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` several times - it should be called once after webdriver instance creation and it will work for the rest of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` node is just a "name" of the input field, you cannot send keys to this element. You need to handle text `input` node instead.

Assuming HTML looks like

```
<div id='txtBoxSearch'>
    <label>Search</label>
    <input type='text'>
</div>
```

You can try

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="txtBoxSearch"]/input[@type="text"]""")
```